# Cassandra Apache : Problems execution cassandra -f

Tags: cassandra

I would to know if it's an obligation to execute cassandra -f for use cassandra-cli or cqlsh ??? Because, i tested connection to cassandra-cli --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9160 or cqlsh and i have a message error : connection failed to localhost/9160

Answer (score 1):

The -f option is a FLAG, so no you don't have to supply it when starting cassandra.

> What does -f get used for?

Depends on the OS but its used for choosing whether to run the process in the foreground / background.

**In Windows**

`-f` means you will run the process in the background. Simply calling cassandra.bat means the process starts in the foreground. E.g:

```
cassandra.bat     # cassandra runs in foreground (i.e.) you see logdata in the terminal
cassandra.bat -f  # cassandra runs in background
```

**In UNIX based OSs (linux / osx)**

Supplying the -f flag means you run the process in the foreground. Not supplying it means the process will start in the background. E.g:

```
cassandra.bat     # cassandra runs in background, you wont see anything in the terminal
cassandra.bat -f  # cassandra runs in foreground
```

**Back to the error**

This means that cassandra isn't running. Start the task manager / activity monitor and verify that Cassandra is executing as a process / service. And also if you want to connect cqlsh / cassandra-cli to a local server without specifying the localhost ip address you can simply type:

```
path/to/cassandra/bin/cqlsh -3      # the -3 means you use CQL3
path/to/cassandra/bin/cassandra-cli
```